# arangoimport command not found

Tags: database, arangodb

Going through the beginner's Arango tutorial and `arangoimport` doesn't work. Please help!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arangoimport` is not in your `PATH` environment variable, thus you need to specify the full path to the executable.

If you use the dmg package for macOS, then the following command should start the import of the airports file:

`/Applications/ArangoDB3-CLI.app/Contents/Resources/arangoimport --file /Users/gtye/Documents/GraphCourse_DemoData_ArangoDB-2/airports.csv --collection airports --create-collection --type csv`